# TypeError: action.default is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-frontend

How to solve this below issue??

```
TypeError: action.default is not a function
    at context.route.load.then.action (/home/go/projects/games/src/router.js:16:1)    
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Answer (score 2):

First, check what is present in `then((action)`

add check `if (action && action.default === 'function')`

if it is true then call the function `action.default`

if statement prevent the TypeError

Comment: can you please check is the default function is available inside the `load: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'archedSearch' */ './games/Arched'),` this file

Comment: Yes export default action